# When and why does the Abyss change people's appearance?

Tags: abyss-2019

In the TV series *Abyss*, the entities who give the Abyss to Cha Min are surprised that his soul has a different appearance from his body. The change in appearance of his body after his resurrection is said to be due to it taking on the appearance of his soul. That is, his resurrected form is younger and better-looking because he's young and heart and a kind person. They even go as far as to suggest that this discrepancy between the appearance says something negative about him. In other words, it's *highly unusual* for the Abyss to change someone's appearances, according to beings who are very familiar with it.

However, at the very least,

> Go Se-Yeon and the serial killer

also changed appearance after being resurrected by the Abyss, making it seem less something unusual about Cha Min and more a general characteristic of human beings. What's more, the former took on the appearance of a *specific person she knew*, which would seem to imply that her her soul looked exactly like that person.

In light of all this, what's really going on when the Abyss changes someone's appearance upon resurrecting them and why is it so common?